# JsonArray in silverlight to javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, json

I'm creating a JsonArray such as:

```
JsonArray jsonValues = new JsonArray();
 for( int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++ )
 {
   var someSingleValue = values[i];
    jsonValues.Add( string.Format( "Name: {0}", someSingleValue ) );
 }
```

After that I'm shipping json values to my javascript in .aspx page via call:
HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("call", jsonValues);

The call works and it gets there, however I have no idea how to iterate over those values, i.e extract them.
I've tried: (in javascript)

```
for (var x in somevalues){ alert(somevalues); }
```

I also tried:

```
 for(var i = 0; i < somevalues.length; i++) {
            alert(somevalues[i]);
            }
```

but it crashes.(in both cases)
any ideas?

Comment: How does the somevalues variable declaration get rendered on the HTML page?

Comment: somevalues will be used to populate drop down list.

Comment: That's not what I asked - I didn't ask about what it is used for, I want to know what gets rendered in the page to declare and initialize the variable called "somevalues."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the eval method to serialize the string to a JSON object?

```
function call(somevalues){

  //somevalues is currently just a string.
  var results = eval("(" + somevalues +")");

  //results now should contain your array as a JSON object.    

  //and you should be able to iterate over it at this point.
  for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
     alert(results[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried using eval before, however I made a mistake and didn't use parenthesis "(" + ")". Thanks!

Comment: Honestly, you shouldn't use eval, you should use a safe JSON parser to turn JSON into a JavaScript object. Google for them, they exist and provide you protections that eval() will not.

Comment: Good tip about not using eval with untrusted input.  I found a project on Google Code that will do it and compares itself to a couple of apparently more common JSON parsers available from json.org

http://code.google.com/p/json-sans-eval/

Answer (score -1):

Assuming somevalues is truly an array, you do it like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < somevalues.length; i++) {
   // do something with somevalues[i]
}
```

What you did was tell JavaScript to iterate over the properties of the `somevalues` object, which is similar, but not the same, as the iteration using a regular `for` loop.

---

EDIT: I am willing to bet your variable, `somevalues` is a string. Just do `alert(somevalues)` and see what happens.

Comment: I've tried that and I get an error: object doesn't support this property or method